# add functions to support original key value hash

Tags: python, data-structures, hashmap, undo-redo

for a hash data structure, it should have 'get', 'set', 'delete' functions, but it also needs to implement 'undo' and 'redo' operations. I am not sure what data structure can support 'undo' or 'redo' operation. Does stack in python can record the previous operations and support undo/redo. Following is original existing hash operations.

```
class Bucket:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bucket = []
    
    def get(self, key):
        for(k, v) in self.bucket:
            if k == key:
                return v
        return -1
    
    def update(self, key, value):
        found = False
        for i, kv in enumerate(self.bucket):
            if key == kv[0]:
                self.bucket[i] = (key, value)
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            self.bucket.append((key, value))


    def remove(self, key):
        for i, kv in enumerate(self.bucket):
            if key == kv[0]:
                del self.bucket[i]


class MyHashMap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.key_space = 2069
        self.hash_table = [Bucket() for i in range(self.key_space)]
        

    def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
        hash_key = key % self.key_space
        self.hash_table[hash_key].update(key, value)
        

    def get(self, key: int) -> int:
        hash_key = key % self.key_space
        return self.hash_table[hash_key].get(key)
        

    def remove(self, key: int) -> None:
        hash_key = key % self.key_space
        self.hash_table[hash_key].remove(key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you interpreted the challenge as if you were not allowed to use -- and extend -- the native `dict`, and tried to implement hashing from scratch.

As far as I understood, that is not the intention of the challenge.

The challenge is to *add* undo/redo functionality to the already existing dictionary features that are available in Python.

You can achieve this by maintaining a standard dict and add undo/redo stacks to the instance. With each call of `set` and `delete` you would do three things:

- Apply that action on the native dict
- Append the opposite action to the undo stack.
- Clear the redo stack

Then when the new `undo` method is called, pop the latest action from that undo stack and do two things:

- Apply that action on the native dict
- Append the opposite action on the **redo** stack.

The `redo` method is similar, just that it pops the action from the **redo** stack and appends the opposite action on the **undo** stack.

Here is an implementation:

```
class UndoableDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}
        self.undostack = []
        self.redostack = []

    def get(self, key):
        return self.dict.get(key)

    def set(self, key, value):
        if key in self.dict:
            prev = self.dict[key]
            self.dict[key] = value
            self.undostack.append(("update", key, prev))
        else:
            self.dict[key] = value
            self.undostack.append(("delete", key, None))
        self.redostack.clear()
        
    def delete(self, key):
        if key in self.dict:
            self.undostack.append(("add", key, self.dict.pop(key)))
            self.redostack.clear()

    # Common algorithm for undo and redo, just with different stacks:
    def _roll(self, fromstack, tostack):
        action, key, value = fromstack.pop()
        if action == "delete":
            tostack.append(("add", key, self.dict[key]))
            self.dict.pop(key)
        elif action == "add":
            tostack.append(("delete", key, None))
            self.dict[key] = value
        else:
            tostack.append(("update", key, self.dict[key]))
            self.dict[key] = value
    
    def undo(self):
        self._roll(self.undostack, self.redostack)

    def redo(self):
        self._roll(self.redostack, self.undostack)
```